# Apache responds with 404 instead of 403, ignoring F flag

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this simple project hierarchy:

[image]

The contents of the `.htaccess` file located at the `/www` root folder are:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} "\.php$"
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

The rule in `.htaccess` should return a **403** when requesting any *.php* file but `index.php`. The contents of the *.php* templates are not relevant.

If i'm not wrong, if the last part of the request is the name of an existing *.php* file and rewrite engine is on, Apache serves it whether you specify the *.php* part or not. In my case, if i comment out the last 2 lines of `.htaccess`, any of these urls:

```
localhost/pages/page 
localhost/pages/page/
```

return the contents of `/pages/page.php`

My issue is that, given the above `.htaccess`, if i write this url:

```
localhost/pages/page.php
```

i get a **403** as expected. But if i write any of:

```
localhost/pages/page
localhost/pages/page/
```

i get a **404** (not found) instead of the expected **403**. Why am i getting the **404**?

Comment: _“if the last part of the request is the name of an existing .php file and rewrite engine is on, Apache serves it whether you specify the .php part or not.”_ - that is not mod_rewrite’s doing, that is the effect of MultiViews. My guess is, it might be interfering here as well, so try and disable it with `Options -MultiViews`.

Comment: @CBroe I've tried with ```Options -MultiViews``` but i get same results

Comment: Without MultiViews enabled, I don’t see how `/www/pages/page` or `/www/pages/page/` would make it find `/www/pages/page.php` in the first place.

Comment: `REQUEST_FILENAME` has not necessarily been resolved to an actual physical file name yet at this point, so it might still contain the same as `REQUEST_URI`. So for `/www/pages/page/`, the test for an existing file by appending `.php` to the end of it, would not work.

Comment: @CBrow i suppose the module that enables that behaviour (content negotiation module i guess?) is enabled by default in my localhost Apache installation. Anyway i have tried to make a 301 redirect to index.php appending ```REQUEST_FILENAME ``` as a querystring parameter: ```RewriteRule . index.php?q=%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [R=301,L]``` and it responds with the actual file path: ```https://localhost/index.php?q=D:/wamp64/www/pages/page.php``` when i enter the url ```https://localhost/pages/page```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting... I can reproduce this behaviour on Apache 2.4, but cannot explain it - it looks like a bug in my opinion, since replacing `F` with `R=403` produces the desired result (there should be no difference) - see below.

To clarify, for `/pages/page` to resolve to `/pages/page.php` in the first place is dependent on `MultiViews` being *enabled* (as already stated in comments). Or, you can do this with mod_rewrite - but there is no evidence of that here. MultiViews is disabled by default on Apache, but some shared hosts do enable it for some reason (it makes extensionless URLs "just work"). However, MultiViews is a common cause of unexpected conflicts with mod_rewrite. And the fact that extensionless URLs "just (unexpectedly) work" can cause additional problems with canonicalisation.

The reason why I think there is a "bug" is that if you simply change the `F` flag to `R=403` then you do get the "expected" 403 response:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} "\.php$"
> RewriteRule .* - [R=403]
> ```

There should be no difference between `F` and `R=403`. AFAIK, `F` is simply a shortcut.

---

> I've tried with `Options -MultiViews` but i get same results

However, with MultiViews *disabled* then a 404 **is** the expected response.

With MultiViews disabled then if you request `/pages/page`, `REQUEST_FILENAME` will be of the form `/abs/path/to/pages/page` (no `.php` extension). Your condition does not match and so the request falls through to a 404.

You are better off working with MultiViews disabled. It is not "normal" for `/pages/page` and `/pages/page/` to "magically" resolve to `/pages/page.php`. It is "normal" for `/pages/page` and `/pages/page/` to result in a 404 in this scenario. If you are doing much with mod_rewrite, where the requested URL maps to the filesystem then you will likely get conflicts.

Note that MultiViews doesn't just apply to `.php` files. With MultiViews enabled you've got extensionless *everything*. Images, scripts, HTML, stylesheets etc. If you have multiple files with a common basename and mime-type, which is going to be served? eg. `foo.php` or `foo.html`?

Of course, you can create mod_rewrite directives to enable this behaviour - but this is not automatic.

---

**UPDATE:** A more concise example...

Given a file `/page.php` (in the document root) and MultiViews is *enabled*.
(eg. `Options +MultiViews`)

Requesting `/page` (or `/page/`) results in MultiViews/mod_negotiation serving `/page.php` via than internal subrequest.

Now, lets block *all* access with mod_rewrite and serve a 403 Forbidden:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

This should block *every* request with a 403. However, requesting `/page` or `/page/` - a URL that is *successfully* rewritten by MultiViews - results in a 404 Not Found response instead!

However, change the above rule to use the `R` flag instead:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403]
```

Now, everything returns a 403, including the two URLs mentioned above! But `F` and `R=403` should result in the same behaviour.

Comment: So should this issue be reported somehow?

Comment: What version of Apache are you running and on what platform? Admittedly I'm testing this on a rather old version of Apache 2.4.7 (on Windows). Need to rule out that it isn't something that's fixed in later versions.

Comment: I'm running Apache 2.4.37 on Windows.